# How can I get the ICCID number of the phone?

Tags: android

How can I get the ICCID number of the phone?

I looked in the TelephonyManager class, but didn't found there a way to get the ICCID number,  there is only a method which tells if the ICC card is present.

Comment: Point of clarification: a _phone_ **does not have** an ICCID. A _sim card_ **does have** an ICCID, and a phone may have zero, one or more sim cards inserted into it at any point in time (depending on the phone model).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe [`getSimSerialNumber()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimSerialNumber()) will get iccid.

**UPDATE** for Android 5.1 (credit [Erick M Sprengel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1489446/erick-m-sprengel))

"Multiple SIM Card Support" was added for [Android 5.1](https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/about/versions/android-5.1.html) (API 22).
Instead of using `getSimSerialNumber`, you can use [`SubscriptionManager`](https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html).

```
SubscriptionManager sm = SubscriptionManager.from(mContext);

// it returns a list with a SubscriptionInfo instance for each simcard
// there is other methods to retrieve SubscriptionInfos (see [2])
List<SubscriptionInfo> sis = sm.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();

// getting first SubscriptionInfo
SubscriptionInfo si = sis.get(0);

// getting iccId
String iccId = si.getIccId();
```

You will need the permission:  (credit [Damian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/249492/damian))

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: iccid is of 20 digits according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscriber_identity_module but this method returns a 19 digit number

Comment: To back that up, my ATT SIM has 20 digits. It's possible that it is different for different carriers. I have tested the function many times and it always functions to my needs, though I haven't actually checked to see how many characters it returns.

Comment: My understanding is SIM serial number and ICCID are same things.

Comment: What will happen when the device has multiple sims inserted? @Reed

Comment: @Reed Does ICCID number depend on the type of SIM like Airtel, Idea, Vodaphone company vendor? Please help me on it

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha, I haven't done mobile dev or tinkered with phones in so long that I don't personally know, but this looks like it might help: his should help: https://www.hologram.io/blog/whats-an-iccid-number-and-why-does-it-matter-for-cellular-iot

Comment: @Reed ... I have checked the above code with different SIM provider,The ID changes as the SIM change in the device..

Comment: Oh, I maybe misunderstood. Yeah, the ICCID is the ID of the sim card itself. From [that link](https://www.hologram.io/blog/whats-an-iccid-number-and-why-does-it-matter-for-cellular-iot), it looked like some of the characters identify the carrier.

Comment: ok,i got iccic length is 12 .but right iccid length is 20  ?

Comment: @Bingchean, https://www.imei.info/faq-what-is-ICCID/ says the "Account Id" is 12 digits. Maybe its returning the account id without the country & character information? I don't know though. I wonder if the phone's hardware settings show you something different? Or if the iccid printed on the physical card is only 12 digits? Maybe its carrier dependent?

Answer (score 7):

It's best not to use this, as this is one of the identifiers that recently got [**restricted**](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/behavior-changes-all), just as was done [**recently on Android 10**](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids).

On Android 11 (API 30), even if you don't target it, you will most likely get just an empty string.

The [**recommendation**](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#mobile-service-subscriptions) of what to use is [**getSubscriptionId**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionInfo#getSubscriptionId()) instead (requires READ_PHONE_STATE permission).

The [**reason**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionInfo#getIccId()):

> Returns the ICC ID. Starting with API level 30, returns the ICC ID if
> the calling app has been granted the READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE
> permission, has carrier privileges (see
> TelephonyManager#hasCarrierPrivileges), or is a device owner or
> profile owner that has been granted the READ_PHONE_STATE permission.
> The profile owner is an app that owns a managed profile on the device;
> for more details see Work profiles. Profile owner access is deprecated
> and will be removed in a future release.

so it returns "the ICC ID, or an empty string if one of these requirements is not met" . For third party apps, this means you will probably always get an empty string.

If you don't meet these (and you usually don't), you can use it.

```
final SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(context);
final List<SubscriptionInfo> activeSubscriptionInfoList = subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
```

And then for each of them, you can use `subscriptionInfo.getIccId()` .

Comment: Does ICCID number depend on the type of SIM like Airtel, Idea, Vodaphone company vendor? Please help me on it

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha I don't know, but as I wrote, it's recommended not to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!!! I have one query please help me out from it that How can uniquely identify any device ? Is there any way or trick to do it? Thanks again

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha Sadly Google decided to restrict it more and more over Android versions, so technically you can gather all that you can from what you get, but know that eventually you will (and it's probably already this way) get multiple devices have the same "ID" that you've generated.  There is no reliable way today to identify a device. You might get a "good enough" solution, but it will never be 100% reliable. One method of getting ID of the device used to be various fields of "android.os.Build" , for example.

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha OK I think I got one thing that you might be able to do, but only in specific cases:  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build#getSerial() . For example, if your app is the default SMS app, you can get the serial of the device. There might be other similar things. I don't know. I just suggest to leave this idea alone.

Comment: Thanks Sir again 

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha If you wish, there is also `Secure.getString(context.contentResolver, Secure.ANDROID_ID)` , but it says that it can get reset on some rare cases, and that it's different for each user on the device

Comment: Yes, It become different for the each applications, I have tested this one earlier.. If in the future , you get some solution on it then please let me know..Again thanks :)

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha You can read the link I've provided for all possible solutions, but again, many can be reset. In the future I don't think Google will make it easier. They tend to make things harder for security/privacy.

Comment: Yes you well said..Way will not be  easy for it

Answer (score 2):

@Jakar, thank you very much!  Here's the same code in C# using Xamarin / Mono.Android

Requires the permission set in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Simple C#

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Telephony;
// ...
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
  base.OnCreate(bundle);

  // Requires, android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
  SubscriptionManager sm = Android.Telephony.SubscriptionManager.From(Android.App.Application.Context);
  IList<SubscriptionInfo> sis = sm.ActiveSubscriptionInfoList;
  SubscriptionInfo si = sis[0];

  string carrier = si.CarrierName;
  string iccId = si.IccId;
  string phoneNum = si.Number;

  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Carrier: " + carrier);
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SIM Card IccId: " + iccId);
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Phone Number: " + phoneNum);

  // Bonus, Get the IMEI Id (aka, DeviceId)
  TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.TelephonyService);
  string deviceId = tm.DeviceId;

  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Device Id: " + deviceId);
}
```

Both **SubscriptionManager** and **SubscriptionInfo** are found under the **Android.Telephony** namespace

Truth be told this example was needed to activate my phone on the fly and not having the SIM card tool handy to pull it out. And, my eyes aren't what they use to be.  View it on [DroidTelephonySimInfo.cs](https://gist.github.com/DamianSuess/2de13c876835dbc8a892c6dbc6224d0f) on gist.github.com

Comment: @VladMatvienko, since this method is using SubscriptionManager I believe the answer is, yes. Feel free to try it out though.
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.1.html